# PHP (Symfony2) arrays : "INNER JOIN"

Tags: php, arrays, entity-framework, symfony, dql

I have an issue where I need to filter a entity based on various entity properties. Some of these properties are linking to other entities in ManyToOne or ManyToMany relationships. I am working in Symfony2 and have come to the conclusion that writing a single DQL query dynamically to filter only by the selected properties is too complex for my level of experience, so what I want to do is retrieve a result set array for every filter property and then merge them, but in such a way that only the array items that exist in BOTH array A and array B will appear in my resulting array. I have been trying to find something that would easily allow me to do this, but I have been unable to find anything.

If any Symfony2 developers look at this thread, I realize that doing it in the way mentioned above is not ideal, so if you could help me create a DQL query that can do this I would be most grateful. Below is my entity that I need to filter results for. The properties that I need to filter by are "categories", "authors", "genre" and "language". Assume that I extract from the REQUEST an array that looks similar to `array('category' => 1, 'genre' => 6, 'author' => 8, 'language' => 2);` of which at least one must be present, but not all of them have to be present.

```
<?php

namespace Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Ser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Ebook
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ebooks")
 * @Ser\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Ebook
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Category[]
      * 
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="ebooks", cascade={"remove"})
      * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
     **/
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @var Author[]
      * 
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Author", inversedBy="ebooks", cascade={"remove"})
      * @ORM\OrderBy({"lastname" = "ASC", "firstnames" = "ASC"})
      * @Ser\Expose
     **/
    private $authors;

    /**
     * @var Curriculum
      * 
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Curriculum", inversedBy="ebooks", cascade={"remove"})
      * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
      * @Ser\Expose
     **/
    private $curriculum;

    /**
     * @var Genre
      * 
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Genre", inversedBy="ebooks", cascade={"remove"})
      * @ORM\OrderBy({"description" = "ASC"})
      * @Ser\Expose
     **/
    private $genre;

    /**
     * @var Language
      * 
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Language", inversedBy="ebooks", cascade={"remove"})
      * @Ser\Expose
     **/
    private $language;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isbn", type="string", length=16, unique=true)
     * @Ser\Expose
     * @Assert\Length(min=4, max=16)
     */
    private $isbn;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="stock_code", type="string", length=16)
     * @Ser\Expose
     * @Assert\Length(min=4, max=16)
     */
    private $stockCode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="grade", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @Ser\Expose
     * @Assert\Type({"int"})
     */
    private $grade;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
     * @Ser\Expose
     * @Assert\Type({"float"})
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=128)
     * @Ser\Expose
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=128)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Ser\Expose
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="year_of_pub", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Ser\Expose
     * @Assert\DateTime
     */
    private $yearOfPub;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ebook_file", type="string", length=256, nullable=true)
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    private $ebookFile;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="thumbnail", type="string", length=256, nullable=true)
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    private $thumbnail;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime")
     * @Ser\Expose
     * @Assert\DateTime
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean")
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="allow_trial", type="boolean")
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    private $allowTrial;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="featured", type="boolean")
     * @Ser\Expose
     */
    private $featured;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // METHODS
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->authors = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->curriculums = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->genres = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->active = true;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set isbn
     *
     * @param string $isbn
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setIsbn($isbn)
    {
        $this->isbn = $isbn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isbn
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getIsbn()
    {
        return $this->isbn;
    }

    /**
     * Set stockCode
     *
     * @param string $stockCode
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setStockCode($stockCode)
    {
        $this->stockCode = $stockCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get stockCode
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getStockCode()
    {
        return $this->stockCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set grade
     *
     * @param integer $grade
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setGrade($grade)
    {
        $this->grade = $grade;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get grade
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getGrade()
    {
        return $this->grade;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param float $price
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set yearOfPub
     *
     * @param \DateTime $yearOfPub
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setYearOfPub($yearOfPub)
    {
        $this->yearOfPub = $yearOfPub;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get yearOfPub
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getYearOfPub()
    {
        return $this->yearOfPub;
    }

    /**
     * Set active
     *
     * @param boolean $active
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get active
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getActive()
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * Add categories
     *
     * @param \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Category $categories
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function addCategory(\Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $categories;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove categories
     *
     * @param \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Category $categories
     */
    public function removeCategory(\Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
    }

    /**
     * Get categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    /**
     * Add authors
     *
     * @param \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Author $authors
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function addAuthor(\Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Author $authors)
    {
        $this->authors[] = $authors;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove authors
     *
     * @param \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Author $authors
     */
    public function removeAuthor(\Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Author $authors)
    {
        $this->authors->removeElement($authors);
    }

    /**
     * Get authors
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getAuthors()
    {
        return $this->authors;
    }

    /**
     * Set language
     *
     * @param \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Language $language
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setLanguage(\Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Language $language = null)
    {
        $this->language = $language;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get language
     *
     * @return \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Language 
     */
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowTrial
     *
     * @param boolean $allowTrial
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setAllowTrial($allowTrial)
    {
        $this->allowTrial = $allowTrial;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get allowTrial
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getAllowTrial()
    {
        return $this->allowTrial;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set featured
     *
     * @param boolean $featured
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setFeatured($featured)
    {
        $this->featured = $featured;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get featured
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getFeatured()
    {
        return $this->featured;
    }

    /**
     * Add categories
     *
     * @param \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Category $categories
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function addCategorie(\Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $categories;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove categories
     *
     * @param \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Category $categories
     */
    public function removeCategorie(\Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
    }

    /**
     * Set curriculum
     *
     * @param \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Curriculum $curriculum
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setCurriculum(\Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Curriculum $curriculum = null)
    {
        $this->curriculum = $curriculum;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get curriculum
     *
     * @return \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Curriculum 
     */
    public function getCurriculum()
    {
        return $this->curriculum;
    }

    /**
     * Set genre
     *
     * @param \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Genre $genre
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setGenre(\Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Genre $genre = null)
    {
        $this->genre = $genre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get genre
     *
     * @return \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Entity\Genre 
     */
    public function getGenre()
    {
        return $this->genre;
    }

    /**
     * Set ebookFile
     *
     * @param string $ebookFile
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setEbookFile($ebookFile)
    {
        $this->ebookFile = $ebookFile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ebookFile
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEbookFile()
    {
        return $this->ebookFile;
    }

    /**
     * Set thumbnail
     *
     * @param string $thumbnail
     * @return Ebook
     */
    public function setThumbnail($thumbnail)
    {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get thumbnail
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getThumbnail()
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://es1.php.net/array_intersect. Also, I'm trying to write a DQL query with your specification, but I don't quite understand it. Could you please post more detailed information?

Comment: Hi Alberto, the premise is that a user is on a site that lists all eBooks. Now he is allowed to filter the eBooks by category, genre, language and author (each of which is an entity to which the eBook links. An eBook can have more than one category and author, but the user only selects one). He can select one of each for all of these, or he can select only one of them (genre for instance) and then "posts" his filter request. My controller function then has to filter the ebooks and return the results based on his filter request.

Comment: So if only "GENRE A" has been selected, then the function must return all eBooks that are linked to "GENRE A", if "GENRE A" and "AUTHOR C" and "LANGUAGE ENGLISH" has been selected, then the function must return all ENGLISH eBooks that are linked to "GENRE A" AND "AUTHOR C".

Comment: The query must this be dynamically generated, based on which filter selections are being sent through in the "REQUEST" which is passed along to the controlller function.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Posted some quick code that might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example on how to achieve that. Assuming you have a `BookRepository` and also a `BookFilterType` which defines what kind of filters the user can use:

```
class BookRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    protected $queryBuilder;

    public function filterByGenre($genre)
    {
        return $this->getQueryBuilder()
            ->andWhere("b.genre = :genre")
            ->setParameter('genre', $genre);
    }

    public function filterByWhatever($whatever)
    {
        return $this->getQueryBuilder()
            ->andWhere("b.whatever = :whatever")
            ->setParameter('whatever', $whatever);
    }

    public function getFilterResult()
    {
        $result = $this->getQueryBuilder()
            ->getQuery->getResult();

        $this->queryBuilder = null;

        return $result;
    }


    public function getQueryBuilder()
    {
        if(!$this->queryBuilder)
            $this->queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder("b");

        return $this->queryBuilder;
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new BookFilterType());

    if($request->isMethod("POST"))
    {
        $form->submit($request);

        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $filters = $form->getData();

            // pass filters to the repository
            $books = $bookRepository
                ->filterByGenre($filters['genre'])
                ->filterByWhatever($filters['whatever'])
                ->getFilterResult();

            return ['books' => $books]; // render filtered books in template
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use a GET form (to pass filters over the URL); that does not matter because it's handled under the hood by the `bind` method.

Comment: Thank you very much, there is just one issue here, which is mainly where I get stuck. Category, for instance is a ManyToOne relationship (so one eBook can have many categories), so if I write `->andWhere(b.category = :category)` I will get an error that 'category' does not exist (as it is defined as categories) and `->andWhere(b.categories = :category)` also does not work.

Comment: In this kind of relationships (and also in `ManyToMany`) you need to first join the relation and then query against that: `join('b.categories', 'cat')->andWhere('cat IN (:categories)')`. Note the use on `IN` when you need books that belongs to *multiple* categories, not just one. You might want to review that also for the rest of fields.